# Why is this change in IB not being reflected on the device?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, interface-builder, uitableview

I am using a static UITableViewCell in my view controller. For some reason unbeknownst to me, this image is 45x45ish on the device(iPhone 5) when it should be 25x25. If I change it's size in IB, it is not reflected on the device. I have tried cleaning the project and installing a fresh build on the device. Does anyone have any advise?

On the device

[image: IB]

In IB
[image: device]

There is no code to show as this is a static cell made in IB.
[image]
[image]

**Edit: Sorry if the question is confusing.**

I have specific for the image on the pccsettingscell to have a width of 25 and height of 25. When I run the app on my device, the image is not of size 25x25.

Comment: not getting your issue... can you please be more clear with it

Comment: provide relevant code related to the `imageView` in question (or anything related to it like xib settings screenshot)

Comment: What constraints do you have on the imageView?

Comment: I am not using auto layout so there are no constraints. There isn't any code to post except for the .h for of the IB Outlets.

Comment: I have added the requested screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Set correct contentMode to your Image view.

UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit - if you want your image to be fit inside your view by scaling in aspect ratio.

Comment: This didn't seem to help correct the image size differences between IB and the device.

Comment: I suggest, remove your current image view and add new image view, set image for that view.

Comment: I had to also set the cell's content mode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit and it worked. Thanks!